# PHP, AJAX e jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Olá. Eu tenho a seguinte hierarquia de pastas:

Pasta "mãe", com o seguinte:
arquivo submit.php, com o seguinte código:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include("libs/submit.php");
```

Pasta /templates, que tem o arquivo `submit.php`, com o seguinte código:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="file" name='foto' id="file-upload" style="display:none;">

    <input type="submit" class="upload_button" value="Submit">

    <div class='editable'>Oi pra mim e pra vc</div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".upload_button").click(function() {
                var descricaoArteHTML = $(".editable").Editor("getText");

                $.ajax({ 
                     url: '/',
                     data: {descricaoArte : descricaoArteHTML},
                     type: 'POST',
                     success: function(output) {
                                  alert(output);
                     },
                     error: function(request, status, error){
                        alert("Error: Could not delete");
                     }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

E a pasta libs/, que tem o arquivo `submit.php` com o seguinte codigo:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario_logado'])){

    include "config.php";
    include "banco.php";
    include "helper.php";

    $tem_erros = false;

    if (tem_post()) {

        if (! isset($_FILES['foto'])) {
            $tem_erros = false;
        } else {
            if (tratar_foto($_FILES['foto'])) {
            $foto = array();
            $foto['arquivo'] = $_SESSION['rand'];
            $foto['descricao'] = $_POST['descricaoArte'];  
            } else {
                $tem_erros = true;
            }
        }


        if (! $tem_erros) {
            gravar_foto($mysqli, $foto);
        }

    }

include "./templates/submit.php";
```

O que aconte é a foto é gravada no banco de dados, porém a descrição não, e obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: descricao in /home/u175477054/public_html/libs/submit.php on line 44

Na parte do Ajax, na parte da URL, já tentei várias formas, mas sempre o obtenho o mesmo erro.

Como conseguir gravar a descriçao no banco?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está a tentar enviar esses dados de duas maneiras mutuamente exclusivas.

Não pode fazer o submit da form e passar aí os dados dos inputs e depois enviar o resto via AJAX com `data: {descricaoArte : descricaoArteHTML},`

Tem de fazer tudo com AJAX ou tudo sem AJAX.

**Sem AJAX:**

Tem de ter uma `<form>` no seu HTML. O HTML poderia ser:

```
<form id="minhaForm" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name='foto' id="file-upload" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="hidden" id="descricao" name="descricao" />
    <input type="submit" class="upload_button" value="Submit" />
    <div class='editable'>Oi pra mim e pra vc</div>
</form>
```

e o jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#minhaForm").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#descricao").val($(".editable").Editor("getText"));
        $(this).off('submit');
        this.submit();
    });
});
```

**Só com AJAX:**

Aí sugiro também ter a `<form>` no HTML (aliás sugiro usar o HTML em cima com o exemplo que vou dar), mas pode mudar o `type` do botão para ele não fazer submit da form.

HTML:

```
<form id="minhaForm" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name='foto' id="file-upload" style="display:none;" />
    <input type="hidden" id="descricao" name="descricao" />
    <input type="button" class="upload_button" value="Submit" />
    <div class='editable'>Oi pra mim e pra vc</div>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".upload_button").click(function () {
        $("#descricao").val($(".editable").Editor("getText"));

        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            data: $('#minhaForm').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (output) {
                alert(output);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert("Error: Could not delete");
            }
        });
    });
});
```