# Como pegar valor de JQuery e passar ao PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Sei que a pergunta já pode ter sido feita, mas em nenhum caso resolveu o problema que tenho, preciso pegar o valor de uma variável JQuery e passar para uma em PHP, a variável em JQuery está sendo criada assim:

```
// Gerando números para cada ciclo do processo  
if( $("#LinkDocumento").val() != "" && $("#Etapa").val() == 1)  {
    var Numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);                
} else if ( $("#LinkDocumento").val() != "" && $("#Etapa").val() == 2) {
    var Numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
} else {
    var Numero = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
}
```

E tentei jogar o valor em uma variável `PHP` assim:

```
 $EtapaForm = "<script>document.write(Numero)</script>";
```

Mas não estou conseguindo, o resultado fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A variável que estou tentando resgatar será passada como parâmetro a um outro formulário que está sendo resgatado através da variável `#LinkDocumento`, ou seja, essa variável me traz do banco um caminho.

Comment: Sugestão de leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43739/129

Comment: Você pode fazer um simples `window.location.href = "url.php?EtapaForm=" + Numero`. Mas o recomendado é utilizar ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma sujestão seria passar para php via ajax.

Tente isso:

```
function passarVariavelJQueryParaPHP(valor){ 
    $.ajax({
        type      : 'post', 
        url       : 'teste.php', 
        data      : 'variavel ='+ valor, 
        dataType  : 'html', 
        error: function(xhr) {
            $("div#error").html('Erro ao passar variavel: ' + xhr.responseText);
        }
      }); 
});
```

E no arquivo teste.php faça:

```
$variavel = $_POST['variavel'];
```