# Como usar comando PHP dentro do javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Eu gostaria de saber como usar comandos PHP(include) dentro do javascript, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
    jQuery(function($)
    {
        var $formteste = $('#fazer_upload_form')
        var $formcadastro = $('#form_cadastro');
        var $formlogin = $('#form_login');

        $formteste.submit(function()
        {
            <?
                include 'testar.php';
            ?>
            $("#painel_fazer_upload").dialog('close');
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Quando eu uso dessa forma o modal nem se quer abre.

O testar.php teria isso:

```
    include("connection.php");

$arquivo_up = $_FILES['arquivo']['name'];
$arquivo_descricao = $_POST['arquivo_descricao'];

if(file_exists("Uploads/$arquivo_up"))
{
    $a = 1;
    while(file_exists("Uploads/[$a]$arquivo_up"))
    {
        $a++;   
    }

    $arquivo_up = "[".$a."]$arquivo_up";    
}

$extensao = pathinfo($arquivo_up, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if($extensao == "torrent")
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], "Uploads/".$arquivo_up))
    {
        $arquivo_up = pathinfo($arquivo_up, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        $sqlupload = mysqli_query($coneccao, "INSERT INTO arquivos_downloads(nome, descricao) VALUES ('$arquivo_up', '$arquivo_descricao')");

        header("location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
                <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Erro no upload do arquivo!')</script>";       
    }   
}
else
{
    echo "  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; url=index.php'>
            <script type='text/javascript'>alert('Formato Invalido!')</script>";
}
```

Obs: Gostaria de saber resumidamente como fazer exatamente isso e não ter que estudar algo sobre isso, obrigado.

Comment: Qual é o objetivo, poderia explicar? isso ai precisa de ajax.

Comment: O que existe dentro do seu `teste.php`? você já viu como fica o seu `HTML` depois que a página renderiza? O que você quer fazer exatamente colocando `php` dentro do `javascript`?

Comment: Em um sistema de login eu mandaria para a pagina testar.php, verificaria o banco de dados, etc e então voltaria para a index.php, em vez de fazer tudo isso gostaria apenas de chamar a pagina testar,php, executar tudo ali mesmo e fechar o modal.

Comment: @LucasCarezia nesse caso precisas de usar AJAX. Sabes o que isso é?

Comment: Sei oque é, mas só sei o básico dele ;C

Comment: @LucasCarezia sugestão de leitura: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43736/129, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6626/129

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma estudada, mas tem alguma "parte" especifica do AJAX que devo estudar pra fazer oque eu quero ??

Comment: Realmente o que você busca é [**ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Mas tem alguma parte especifica dele que devo estudar para executar oque eu quero ??

Comment: Coloca na pergunta o conteudo desse ficheiro php para percebermos o que queres fazer.

Comment: Coloquei sim, oque devo fazer ??

Comment: Lucas, chegou a ver o link da pergunta no topo da página a solução da sua dúvida?

Comment: Vi, fiz uns testes e não consegui do mesmo jeito, por isso votei para reabrir.